# How to access an injected service in parent component from child

Tags: blazor

Consider the following code to be in `ParentComponent.razor`:

```
@inject HttpClient Http
<h1>Parent</h1>
@code{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("test", "true");
    }
}
```

and `ChildComponent.razor`:

```
@inherits ParentComponent
<h1>Child</h1>
@code{
    
}
```

How can I access and use `Http` object in the child component?

Comment: O' fellow SO user who has voted this question down, how can I improve my clear and useful honest question? Please leave a comment for the next person so your opinion might get taken to action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject the service from `@code` to make it accessible for inheriting components.

```cs
<h1>Parent</h1>
@code{
    [Inject]
    public HttpClient Http { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("test", "true");
    }
}
```

Use `base` to access it.

```cs
@inherits ParentComponent
<h1>Child</h1>
@code{
    private void DoSomething(){
       System.Uri baseAddress = base.Http.BaseAddress;
    }
}
```

Comment: T.Trassoudaine - you should add `=default!;` to the injected service to suppress the null warnings.  The  Razor compiler does it by placing the inject at the bottom of the class file and just before the declaration setting `#nullable disable`.

Comment: I really like your answer, but what if there is more than 1 parent? Often times you want to make components to put across multiple pages. How could you inherit at that point?

Comment: @user2455808 What do you mean by "more than 1 parent" ? You can only `@inherits` once per component so there is always one parent per component. Do you mean multiple parent in terms of inheriting multiple times ("grandparent") or in terms of instantiating/calling the component in multiple locations?